# Is it possible to 'transform' a HMap into another HMap

Tags: scala, shapeless

If I have a [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) `HMap[MappingA]` (with implicits properly defined for the type `MappingA[K, V]`), can I type-safely transform/map it to a `HMap[MappingB]`.

```scala
class MappingA[K, V]
implicit val intToString = new MappingA[Int, String]
implicit val stringToInt = new MappingA[String, Int]

class MappingB[K, V]
implicit val longToString = new MappingA[Long, String]
implicit val stringToLong = new MappingA[String, Long]

val hm1 = HMap[MappingA](1 -> "one", "two" -> 2)

// How to...
val hm2: HMap[MappingB] = ??? // transform/map hm1

// expected for hm2 in this basic example
// HMap[MappingB](1L -> "one", "two" -> 2L)
```

Comment: There's no type-safe way to enumerate the contents of an `HMap` (in the current API—it's possible to imagine one), so I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks @TravisBrown . If it can be imagined, I think that would be somethink valuable :)

Comment: Well, what I'm imagining is just maintaining an `HList` of keys next to the map, and since that has a runtime cost I doubt it'll ever be part of `HMap` itself.