# Is there a way iterate on contents of a shapeless HMap (heterogeneous map)?

Tags: scala, shapeless

I'm trying to implement some sort of polymorphic cache when translating a source AST1 to a target AST2 (building a DSL compiler in scala). Since I wanted the cache to retain precise types for the translation results I had a go with shapeless HMap. It works as intended, however at some point I need to iterate on the cache contents to dump it to a file that must document the translation process, and would later be used to construct a backtranslation from A2 to A1. By looking at the source code of HMap I saw there is an underlying HashMap[Any, Any] that I cannot access since it is not a val in the HMap, and I saw that the HMap was in fact a Polymorphic function value, which means I can apply it over an HList which types correspond to a subset of the HMap key's types, but what I would really like to do is to be able to fold a polymorphic function which accepts polymorhic (key,value) arguments over this HMap to retrieve its contents in another form (for instance sliced in a tuple of standard HashMaps). Is there any way to do that?
Best.

Comment: [Here's some discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29647245/is-it-possible-to-transform-a-hmap-into-another-hmap#comment47438440_29647245) of a similar question from last year.